# Adding a plus sign before positive numbers using NumberSymbol in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am displaying a number the following way:

```
{{product.weight}}
```

I would like to make it so if the number is positive it shows with a + sign.

I see documentation on something called NumberSymbol which is an enum but not sure how to properly use it with a pipe:

https://angular.io/api/common/NumberSymbol

Comment: You only need to create a pipe if you will be needing to add a "+" many times. If it's a single/few cases use the below answer. If you're doing it tens/hundreds of times I can provide an answer with a pipe that does the equivalent.

Comment: @Z.Bagley No need for that now. But it would be a custom pipe correct? Just want to make sure I am not missing out on a built in pipe.

Comment: That's correct, it's custom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
{{product.weight > 0 ? '+' + product.weight : product.weight}}
```

Comment: Parser Error: Unexpected token Lexer Error: Unexpected character [`]

Comment: {{product.weight > 0 ? `+${product.weight}` : product.weight}} It won't let me put the back ticks in here, but it is exactly your solution. I don't think it likes the backticks with the + or next to the brackets.

Comment: @BlakeRivell updated answer without interpolation in template

Answer (score 1):

If you want number formatting, and don't want a custom pipe, use this:

```
{{product.weight > 0 ? '+' : ''}}{{product.weight | number}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use pipe for number formatting, then add sign with another "block":

```
<!-- Sign -->
<ng-container *ngIf="product.weight > 0">
    +
</ng-container>
<!-- Value -->
{{ product.weight | number }}
```